# What determines the relative coordinates of a PyQt widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, move

When I use `move(x, y)` function in PyQt, to which exact coordinates does the widget move? I figured that `x` and `y` are relative to something, but to what?

Answer (score 2):

**X and Y are relative to the coordinate space of the parent widget**

Here is a runnable little example that will show you how the move is relative to the parent of the widget. The parent can be `None`, which means a top level widget that will float. Regardless, it is always relative to the coordinate of the parent all the way up to the screen coordinates.

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from random import randint

from collections import deque

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        mainLayout.setMargin(20)

        self.widgets = deque()
        self.widgets.append(None)
        self.widgets.append(self)

        for i in xrange(3): 
            w = QtGui.QWidget()
            name = "widget%d" % i
            color = [str(randint(0,255)) for _ in xrange(3)]
            w.setObjectName(name)
            w.setStyleSheet("#%s { background: rgb(%s) }" % (name, ','.join(color)))
            mainLayout.addWidget(w)
            self.widgets.append(w)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Move", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.random_move)

    def random_move(self):
        b = self.button
        parent = b.parent()
        pos = b.pos()
        name = parent and parent.objectName() or "None"
        print "\nOld Parent/Pos: ", name, (pos.x(), pos.y())

        new_parent = parent 
        while new_parent is parent:
            self.widgets.rotate(1)
            new_parent = self.widgets[0]

        self.button.setParent(new_parent)
        self.button.move(randint(0, 50), randint(0, 50))
        pos = b.pos()
        name = new_parent and new_parent.objectName() or "None"
        print "New Parent/Pos: ", name, (pos.x(), pos.y())
        self.button.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(800,600)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Every time you click the button it will reparent to a different widget, and use a random move. You will get a print out of the previous parent and position vs the new parent and position. It will always be relative to the **top-left corner** of that parent.

Comment: +1. Nice example. May I suggest adding `desktop = QtGui.qApp.desktop(); desktop.setObjectName("Desktop"); self.widgets.append(desktop)` to `__init__` to demonstrate the `None` case? (EDIT: that would also need `parent = b.parent() or QtGui.qApp.desktop()`)

Comment: @ekhumoro: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a `None` value directly, instead of using the desktop widget reference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the widget has parent or not. If it does, the co-ordinates are relative to the parent widget; otherwise, they are relative to the desktop.

See the [documentation for `move()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop), and the [window geometry overview](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) for further details.